# Creating my own data types with sequences of 1 and 0s

Tags: c, finite-automata

Hi what I am trying to do is create a data type I can use which consists of only two characters (0,1). I am doing this so I can limit the alphabet in my finite automata string algorithm. I am programming in C so I was wondering how I can do this because the character data type is 256 hence too large.

EDIT::
http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-perform-finite-state-automaton-based-search/

I found another implementation of my code in the link above. What I am trying to do is change the variable NO_OF_CHARS to 2 so only two different characters can be used.

Below is the code for my main if it helps.

```
int main()
{
     char a[]="101111";
     char b[]="10";
     int m=strlen(a);
     int n=strlen(b);
     SearchString(a,b,n,m);
     return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think anyone can understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Use `bool` from `stdbool.h`. Or define enum with just two values.

Comment: @iharob: He wants a data type whose only accepted values are 0 and 1.  The smallest type he is aware of is char, which lets you put 0..255, so it is too permissive.

Comment: @jonn Are you trying to save memory, or just enforce the rules that the value can only be 0 or 1?

Comment: Just enforce the rule that it can be 0 or 1; I currently have      char a[]="101111";
    char b[]="10";   as my text and pattern. I want to declare a function void createTransitionFunction(int TF[][2],char *b,int m) for the finite automata string matching algorithm which currently doesnt work because the 2 has to be 256 for char for it to work.

Comment: There aren't types smaller than a `char` in standard C; of course you can use a bool or an enum, but they are simply compile-time checks that somewhat limit the stuff you can put in your variables. You can always obtain the same effect by using chars and storing in them only 1 or 0.

Comment: @jonn I didn't quite understand why *"the 2 has to be 256 for char"*. I think that's the key to what you're trying to do, but I don't know exactly what you mean by that. Can you elaborate, or give an example?

Comment: Because The only characters I am using are 0 and 1s. I dont want to use the others because it increases the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then what you want is to declare an array like `int TF["111"]["10"]` to mean an array of 7x2, is that correct?

Comment: yes I want it to loop through only 0 and 1. Not all 256 characters

Comment: Why do you feel forced to loop through all 256 characters, and not just `'0'..'1'`? Your code does not shed any light on what you want to do with `void createTransitionFunction(int TF[][2],char *b,int m)`

Comment: @jonn I made an edit to the question based on my understanding of the problem. If I got it wrong, please feel free to reverse my edit, thanks.

Comment: I found another implementation of finite string automata which is similar to mine: http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-perform-finite-state-automaton-based-search/ Its the variable NO_OF_CHARS I want to change to 2 which only allows 0 and 1s

Comment: Ok, that's good information that needs to be put into the question, so that people can see what you're trying to do. I rolled back my edit to remove the clutter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `bool` type for this, since `bool`s can just store zeros and ones. Alternatively, consider using an enumerated type, such as

```
enum AutomataCharacter {Zero, One};
```

Using these types will at least raise a compiler warning (if you crank up the warning level) if you try assigning it something of the wrong type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There won't be a warning in C (but in C++ since enums are distinct types).